# display aggregate function output in trailer record

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are reading csv file input which has two fields. Sample input file is given for reference

```
source, balance
1,100
2, 200
```

I need to create a trailer record in the output that the following details-

- number of records in the csv file(excluding file header)
- sum of values in column "balance" of the input file

In our case, the trailer record will be -

```
Trailer 02   300
```

How can I achieve this in data factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have repro’d with your sample data and was able to add the trailer record with aggregated values using Data flow.

1. Add **source1** with the source data set.

[image]

2. Add a `derived column` transformation to create a dummy column with a dummy value.

[image]

3. Add `pivot` transformation to get the aggregate value for trailer record.

[image]

`concat('Trailer ',toString(count(source)),' ',toString(sum(toInteger(balance))))`

[image]

[image]

4. Add **source2** with the same source dataset as source 1.

[image]

5. Add `union` transformation to source2 and select pivot transformation as union with the stream to combine trailer record from pivot with source dataset of source2.

[image]

6. Add `sink` transformation after the union and in settings select **output to single file** and provide an output filename.

[image]

Sink preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use some nearby SQL resource to do this kind of formatting with CTEs and UNION ALL.  I am just using dummy data here to demonstrate the principle, but in terms of adding a trailing record, calculating the trailer records dynamically etc then something like this would work:

```
;WITH cte ( xsort, source, balance ) AS (
SELECT
10,
'1', 100 
UNION ALL
SELECT 20, '2', 200
)
SELECT source, balance
FROM
    (
    SELECT xsort, source, balance
    FROM cte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        30, 
        CONCAT( 'Trailer ',
            FORMAT( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte ), '00' ),
            ' ',
            ( SELECT SUM(balance) FROM cte ) 
            ) x, 
        NULL
    ) x
ORDER BY xsort;
```